# Printf Statement not working on lambda

Tags: c, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, node-gyp

I tried to create a lambda function using node.js. w wrote code in C code and convert it to node library using node-gyp. lambda function perfectly working. but it print only node.js console.log statements.

This is my node.js code

```
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

var addon = require('./build/Release/testLibraryfromCcode');

addon.sayHello();
console.log("Completed");
}
```

This is my C code

```
int sayHello()
{
    printf("Haaaaaaaaaaaaai\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;   
}
```

I got output like this from lambda test console

```
   TART RequestId: 3e8cd5ff-2d41-11e6-af8f-ada8f1249113 Version: $LATEST
    2016-06-08T06:21:32.779Z    3e8cd5ff-2d41-11e6-af8f-ada8f1249113    Loading function
   2016-06-08T06:21:32.779Z 3e8cd5ff-2d41-11e6-af8f-ada8f1249113 Completed
```

Haaaaai print is missing. 
i need to print printf statements in my C code. if any idea?

Comment: have you tried to `fflush(stdout)` after your printf?

Comment: tried. but still not working. question updated

Comment: Can you post your C code that exports `sayHello` function?

Answer (score 5):

This code is working. fflush(stdout) is enogh for printing.

```
int sayHello()
{
    printf("Haaaaaaaaaaaaai\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;   
}
```

But, aws lamda cannot print library prints directly on web console. We need to install awslogs for waching full logs.

1. install awslogs

   > sudo pip install awslogs
2. for Waching logs.

   > awslogs get /aws/lambda/lambdaFunctionName  --start="3h"